# How can I type a "polymorphic" React component?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to type a React component which can "wrap" a value that is either a `number` or a `number[]`, but not both at the same time. This is (a contrived version of) the declaration I've got so far:

```
export interface Props<T> {
  value: T;
}

class SomeComponent<T extends number | number[]> extends React.Component<Props<T>, any> {
  getValue(): T;
}
```

My problem is I don't know 1. If the declaration is correct and 2. How I could use it. I'm trying/want to do something like this right now, but it's a syntax error:

```
const foo: number = 123;
return <SomeComponent<number> value={foo} />
```

How could I declare and use a component that works like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you can't use generics in tsx tags. You can instantiate the component using regular TS syntax:

```
var cNumber = new SomeComponent<number>({
    value : 0 
});
var cNumberArray = new SomeComponent<number[]>({
    value: [1, 2, 3]
});
```

Another option is to declare extra types that fix the type parameters:

```
let SomeNumberComponent: new ()=> SomeComponent<number> =  SomeComponent as any;
```

OR

```
class SomeIntComponent extends SomeComponent<number> {

}
```

**Note** This limitation is also highlighted [here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/generics.html)